# После удаления rapidjson::Document rapidjson::Value больше не хранит значение

Tags: c++, json, c++17

Мне нужно написать функцию, которая из JSON достанет все обьекты и вернет `std::list<rapidjson::Value::Object>`, который их содержит. Вот моя реализация:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <document.h>
#include <list>

std::list<rapidjson::Value::Object> foo()
{
    static rapidjson::Document d;
    d.SetArray();
    d.Parse("{\"method\":[{\"exampleName\" : \"example\"}, {\"exampleName\" : \"example2\"}, {\"exampleNmae\" : \"example3\"}]}");

    std::list<rapidjson::Value::Object> exampleList;
    
    auto it = exampleList.begin();

    for (auto& i : d["method"].GetArray())
    {
        exampleList.push_back(i.GetObject());
    }

    return exampleList;
}

int main()
{
    auto result = foo();

    return 0;
}
```

Но я столкнулся со следующей проблемой: `exampleList` в себе хранит все необходимые мне объекты, но после завершения работы функции я заметил, что `result` содержит пустые объекты. Далее я пытался отладить этот код и заметил, что если сделать переменную `d` статичной, то все работает, как задумано. Однако такое решение проблемы меня не устраивает.

Почему при очистке `rapidjson::Document` `rapidjson::Value` более не хранит значение и в этом ли проблема? Как я могу это исправить?

Comment: `Object` - это вспомогательный класс для доступа к данным, хранящимся в `Value`

Comment: @user7860670 учту, спасибо) а почему у меня элементы списка в resullt пустые?

Comment: Потому что данных, на которые они ссылались, больше нет.

Comment: @user7860670 то есть все Value и другие сущности - это просто ссылки на содержимое документа?

Comment: Я же написал - Object  это вспомогательный класс для доступа к данным, хранящимся в Value